# type '(dynamic) => Set<Text>' is not a subtype of type '(String, String) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider

I am new to flutter. I have `userData` that starts off as a blank dictionary and as users continue through the page it will fill up for example:

```
var userData = {
"Color": "muted",
"Size": "42",
}
```

I would like to map these out into text at the bottom of the page for the user to see

```
Your selected style/sizes
Color: muted
Size: 42
```

Here is my current code for this component and I am using `provider` to grab `userData`:

```
Visibility(
              visible:
                  context.watch<HomeProvider>().userData == {} ? false : true,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text(
                        'Your selected style/sizes',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: context.watch<HomeProvider>().userData == {}
                            ? []
                            : context.watch<HomeProvider>().userData.map(
                                  (e) => {
                                    Text(e),
                                  },
                                ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

But whatever I try to do to display the data I get this error

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope<HomeProvider?>], state: HomePageState#d145b):
type '(dynamic) => Set<Text>' is not a subtype of type '(String, String) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'
```

which is being cause by the line with `.map()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `userData` is a map, you need first to get the entries, this will solve your problem:

```
context.watch<HomeProvider>().userData.entries.map<Widget>((e) => Text(e.value)).toList()
```

Comment: this is the error i am now getting
type '(dynamic) => Text' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: I forgot `userData` was a map, please check my updated answer

Comment: sorry this is still going on, but i am now getting type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine, are you sure you deleted the `{}` after `=>` that were wrapping `Text`?

Comment: still trying to understand why but i had to add <widget> after map like so, context.watch<HomeProvider>() .userData .entries.map<Widget>((e) => Text(e.value)) .toList() and now it works fine, thank you for your help

Comment: Nice, good to know, i added it to the answer just in case is useful to anyone else.